# Binding property to RelativeLayout.XConstraint in XAML Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a problem with binding a property value from my Model objects to the `RelativeLayout.XConstraint` property in XAML.

I got a model, with a property called `public int StartLocation { get; set; }`, but if I bind this property to my `RelativeLayout.XConstraint` on a simple `BoxView` element, it doesnt set the X Constraint Property. I first tried doing this

```
<RelativeLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Broadcasts}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="PaleVioletRed" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{Binding StartLocation}" WidthRequest="{Binding Length}" HeightRequest="60" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I got two bindings here. StartLocation and Length, and the Length Binding works fine, but with this approach it sets the `BoxView` elements xConstraint to the start (I think it is the relative X position 0).

I also tried this approach

```
<RelativeLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Broadcasts}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="PaleVioletRed" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant={Binding StartLocation}}" WidthRequest="{Binding Length}" HeightRequest="60" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I get an error when I run my code saying ***Cannot assign property "Constant": Property does not exist, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property***

[image: Cannot assign property "Constant": Property does not exist, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property]

I hope someone can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does StartLocation call OnPropertyChanged when being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have been wrestling with a similar issue for some time now. I managed to solve it today with a neat workaround. Here's what I did:

(Xaml)

```
            <RelativeLayout x:Name="aviGroup" BindingContext="this"
               RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=1, Constant=1000}"
               RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=1, Constant=25}">

                <Grid x:Name="aviGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Button x:Name="Settings" Text="more" BackgroundColor="Transparent" ImageSource="{local2:ImageResource Buddy.Images.settings_icon.png}" TextColor="Transparent" Clicked="Settings_Clicked" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

                    <BoxView x:Name="buttonBorder" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="54" WidthRequest="54" CornerRadius="24" Margin="5" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />

                    <ImageButton x:Name="userAvi" Source="{DynamicResource currentAVI}" Clicked="userAvi_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="48" WidthRequest="48" CornerRadius="22" Aspect="AspectFill" Margin="8" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                </Grid>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

(Code behind)

```
        private void cV_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Width > 100)
            {

                if (Settings.X > 0) 
                {

                    PostX = Application.Current.MainPage.Width - 300;

                    Constraint newX = Constraint.Constant(PostX);

                    RelativeLayout.SetXConstraint(aviGroup, newX);                  

                }
              
            }
        }
```

Explanation: I have a trigger raised when my content view is resized, which calls cV_PropertyChanged. In this method, I calculate where I want the new x to be, create a new constraint with this value, and then call RelativeLayout.SetXConstraint with the view I want to bind and its new value.

This may not fit your project 1:1, but I hope you can make use of this workaround as well.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I actually went to use an Absolute Layout instead, where I had a Property of the Xamarin Forms Rectangle class for the AbsoluteLayout Bounds property. But thx for you answer. Maybe it can help others.